# creating axes with for loop subplot2grid

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, multiple-axes

I have this code for displaying the first 10 columns of some pandas dataframe...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


## DATAFRAME ##

np.random.seed(102030)              # Se deben correr las 2 lineas juntas SIEMPRE.
df_np = np.random.randint(-100,100,(20,10))
df_index = list(range(1,21))
df_col = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = df_np, 
                  index = df_index, 
                  columns = df_col)


## PLOT ##

f_sample = 1     # First SAMPLE
l_sample = 20    # Last SAMPLE

data_color = 'red'     # FILL COLOR
data_alpha = 0.5    # (0-1) 0-TRANSPARENT 1-OPAQUE --> alpha parameter

df_nan = df * 0.7

fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10)) #Set up the plot axes


ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan = 1) 
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,1), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,2), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,3), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,4), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,5), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,6), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax8 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,7), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax9 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,8), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
ax10 = plt.subplot2grid((1,10), (0,9), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)

axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9, ax10]


for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(df_nan.iloc[:,i], df_nan.index, lw=0)
    ax.set_ylim(l_sample, f_sample)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.set_title(df_nan.columns[i])                                                        
    ax.set_facecolor('whitesmoke')
    ax.fill_betweenx(df_nan.index, 0, df_nan.iloc[:,i], facecolor= data_color, alpha= data_alpha )       
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible = False)
    if i > 0:
        plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible = False)
        
ax1.set_ylabel('Sample', fontsize=18)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
                                      
plt.show()
```

---

It works well when the length of the df is greater or equal than 10 columns..

I would like to have a code for displaying all columns of any df keeping the same display as the previous plot.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED ANSWER

#### Solution

Create axes within a for loop. By changing the range of the loop, you will be able to change the number of columns displayed. This number can be arbitrarily large.

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

## DATAFRAME ##

numCols = 13    # THIS IS THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS IN THE DF WHICH WILL BE DISPLAYED

np.random.seed(102030)              # Se deben correr las 2 lineas juntas SIEMPRE.
df_np = np.random.randint(-100,100,(20,numCols))
df_index = list(range(1,21))
df_col = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = df_np, 
                  index = df_index, 
                  columns = df_col[:numCols])


## PLOT ##

f_sample = 1     # First SAMPLE
l_sample = 20    # Last SAMPLE

data_color = 'red'     # FILL COLOR
data_alpha = 0.5    # (0-1) 0-TRANSPARENT 1-OPAQUE --> alpha parameter

df_nan = df * 0.7

fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10)) #Set up the plot axes

for i in range(numCols):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((1,numCols), (0,i), rowspan=1, colspan = 1)
    ax.plot(df_nan.iloc[:,i], df_nan.index, lw=0)
    ax.set_ylim(l_sample, f_sample)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.set_title(df_nan.columns[i])                                                        
    ax.set_facecolor('whitesmoke')
    ax.fill_betweenx(df_nan.index, 0, df_nan.iloc[:,i], facecolor= data_color, alpha= data_alpha )       
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible = False)
    if i > 0:
        plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible = False)
    else:    # Sets the label for the leftmost subplot
        ax.set_ylabel('Sample', fontsize=18)
    
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)                                   
plt.show()
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

#### Solution

```
allData = [data1, data2, ... , data10]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, figsize=(4,3))

for ax, data in zip(axes.flat, allData):
    ax.imshow(data)
```

#### Explanation

`allData` is some array-like data structure where each element is the data for each subplot. When creating `fig,axes` the `fig` is a Figure and the variable `axes` is an array of subplots. `nrows` and `ncols` determine the number and position of the subplots. If you call a for loop which zips elements from `axes` and `allData` then make sure to flatten your array of subplots.

Link to documentation:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: I put all the code because i couldn't catch the explanation

Comment: @grojar I changed my answer to use `plt.subplot2grid(...)` which should be what you are looking for!